# Why batch script not running with Task scheduler?

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, networking, server

I created a simple batch script to copy WAL Archive logs from local `D:\` drive to share drive `Z:\`, Here is the script :

```
@ECHO OFF
net use Z: "\\PH-NAS-eMB\eMB Backup\"
C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe D:\test_robocopy_1\  Z:\test_robocopy\  /MIR /TEE /LOG+:D:\robocopy_log.txt
PAUSE
```

I created task scheduler to run every **30 minutes** but logs are not copying to Z:\ drive. when i try to run it manually then it working fine.

Any special permission required for task scheduler to run this script every 30 minutes.

Comment: as I understand, task run but log is not created in z drive, right? then, as you have mapped the network resource, there is a permission issue over z drive. once thing is run task on local computer with some credentials, other that such credentials have  write permission over z drive. check it (and get sure that map is done). one more point, remove the pause command, script is running unattended!

Comment: Okay.. thank you i will try and let you know

Comment: You should *not* use the task scheduler, but PostgreSQL's `archive_command` for that.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe WAL Logs are saving in local drive D:\,  but we want them to synch to remote drive Z:\ as per client requests.

Comment: Then make `archive_command` copy the WAL segments to the remote drive.

Comment: Why map drives at all. One Microsoft programmer who had to implement a network driver for MSDos chose to make it as a drive letter. We've been using UNC paths for the last 25 years at least. `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: Thank you , it working with net use command but task scheduler Running very long time . New instance not starting in 30 mins ,  why Task scheduler running more than 30 minst.

Comment: @maredi-naveenkumar by default tasks are created with low priority class, read the last paragraph of https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8425#p55881 to change priority

Comment: i am running this script with task scheduler for every 5 minutes and getting error as below

@ECHO OFF
net use Z: \\PH-NAS-eMB\eMB Backup /user:domain.local\username password
C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe D:\test_robocopy_1  Z:\test_robocopy  /MIR /TEE /LOG+:D:\copy_log.txt

2020/05/13 11:29:10 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Creating Destination Directory Z:\test_robocopy\
The system cannot find the path specified.